# Equation involving infinite sums

Tags: calculus, number-theory

Let $a_i = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^{3n+i}}{(3n+i)!}$   Prove that $a_0^3 + a_1^3 + a_2^3 - 3 a_0a_1a_2 = 1$.

I guess I could factor the given expression, which is fairly intuitive. Apparently one of the hints said to use differential calculus. I think one could convert the sum to a more useful, closed form, but I have no idea how. **Please** don't use **overly** complicated math in the solution or skip wayyy too many steps.

Edit: Oh right! I forgot about the fact that e^x could be expressed as an infinite sum (I.e. a Taylor expansion).

Comment: Factor $a_0^3+a_1^3+a_2^3-3a_0a_1a_2$ into $(a_0+a_1+a_2)(a_0+wa_1+w^2a_2)(a_0+w^2a_1+wa_2)$, with $w=e^{2\pi i/3}$. Then you only need to evaluate the factors, which are linear combinations of series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use
$$a_0+a_1+a_2=e^x,$$
$$a_0+\omega a_1+\omega^2 a_2=e^{\omega x}$$
and
$$a_0+\omega^2 a_1+\omega a_2=e^{\omega^2 x}$$
where $\omega=\exp(2\pi i/3)$.

Comment: thanks! taking advantage of the fact that $a_0+a_1+a_2 = (x^0/0!+x^3/3! + x^6/6! + ...)+(x^1/1!+x^4/4!+x^7/7! + ...)+(x^2/2! + x^5/5! + x^8/8!+...) =e^x$.